# how to use webpack-dev-middleware with typescript?

Tags: typescript, webpack, babeljs, webpack-dev-middleware

I'm trying to implement a simple backend app with express + webpack + babel + typescript, I've seen examples of webpack-dev-middleware where the start script is simply "node index.js", as I understand it, an in-memory server is created with your express application. But how can I implement it using typescript? One possible solution I saw is to use ts-node to run it, but wouldn't that defeat the purpose of using the babel transpilation? am I getting something wrong?
here is my index.ts

```
import express from 'express';
import { webpack } from 'webpack';
import webpackDevMiddleware from 'webpack-dev-middleware';

const config = require('../webpack/webpack.dev.js');

const compiler = webpack(config);

const app = express();

app.use(
  webpackDevMiddleware(compiler, {
    publicPath: config.output.publicPath,
  })
);

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('listening...');
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I work on an app that uses this architecture, and it was setup to use pure Node.js code for the build scripts, so Babel, TS and all that isn't involved at all. The TypeScript and Babel transpiling only comes into play for the actual app code.